# how do I reference an adjacent library in a python zipfile

Tags: python, import, module, relative-path

I have a collection of libraries in python that I need to have in a single zip file.

The structure is:

```
rootlib
   |
   --- lib_a
   |     |
   |     --- lib_a.py
   |
   --- lib_b
         |
         --- lib_b.py
```

I want to be able to reference lib_b from lib_a.  When unzipped, I can load lib_b from lib_a.lib_a.py simply by doing:

```
from lib_b import lib_b
```

but when I zip up the rootlib folder and use it in a script like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/myuser/rootlib.zip')
from rootlib.lib_a.lib_a import LibA
```

I get an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rootlib.lib_a.lib_a import LibA
  File "/home/user/rootlib.zip/rootlib/lib_a/lib_a.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lib_b.lib_b
```

How do I reference/import the adjacent lib_b library from lib_a?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: Add a `__init__.py` to the rootlib folder. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that having the rootlib included in the zip file is a problem

```
   --- lib_a
   |     |
   |     --- lib_a.py
   |
   --- lib_b
         |
         --- lib_b.py
```

Everything works fine when you don't have a root directory.